# Magento 2 : How to override product detail page in custom module

Tags: magento2, product, overrides

I want to override product detail page in custom extension for all types of product. I need some changes around below area

[image]

Any One know about this, please guide me

Comment: are you want to override xml file?

Comment: Which portion you need to override? There are different files for Tabs, Price, Image. so

Comment: above product is configurable product.

Comment: @Rakesh, yes this is configurable product. And i  want solution for all types of product likes(simple, configurable, virtual, bundle, downlable etc). I need to add some instruction for all types of product

Comment: but please show at which place you want to instruction for product page? any screenshot or demo?

Comment: I want some changes at above Add to cart button.